# Python pandas drop columns if their partial name is in a list or column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following dataframe called `dropthese`.

```
     | partname        | x1 | x2 | x3....
0      text1_mid1
1      another1_mid2
2      yet_another
```

And another dataframe called `df` that looks like this.

```
     text1_mid1_suffix1 | text1_mid1_suffix2 | ... | something_else | another1_mid2_suffix1 | ....
0       .....
1       .....
2       .....
3       .....
```

I want to drop all the columns from `df`, if a part of the name is in `dropthese['partname']`.

So for example, since `text1_mid1` is in `partname`, all columns that contain that partial string should be dropped like `text1_mid1_suffix1` and `text1_mid1_suffix2`.

I have tried,

```
thisFilter = df.filter(dropthese.partname, regex=True)
df.drop(thisFilter, axis=1)
```

But I get this error, `` TypeError: Keyword arguments `items`, `like`, or `regex` are mutually exclusive ``. What is the proper way to do this filter?

Comment: If memory serves me correctly: `df[~df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(dropthese['partname']))]`

Comment: Is Partname always the beginning of the word?

Comment: Can you provide DataFrame constructors for reproducibility?

Comment: @Corralien yes it is

Comment: Then use `match` in place of `contains` in my answer to match the start of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (or [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) if you want to restrict to the start of string):

```
import re
pattern = '|'.join(dropthese['partname'].map(re.escape))

out = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(f'({pattern})')]
```

Output:

```
   something_else
0             ...
```

##### Why your command failed

you should pass the pattern to the `regex` parameter of `filter`, and use the column names in `drop`:

```
pattern = '|'.join(dropthese['partname'].map(re.escape))
thisFilter = df.filter(regex=pattern)
df.drop(thisFilter.columns, axis=1)
```